# Can grep read from a file and stdin at the same time?

Tags: grep

`file1`:

```
abcds
asdt5ds
```

`file2`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Output:

```
asdt5ds
5
```

Is it possible to get such output using a variation of `cat file1 | grep 5 file2`?

Comment: `cat file1 | grep 5 /dev/stdin file2` should work, or `cat file[12] | grep 5` or `grep -h 5 file1 file2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [special file `-`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Usage) (for "standard input"):

```
cat file1 | grep 5 - file2
```

If you want to suppress the filenames, i.e., if you don't want this output

```
(standard input):asdt5ds
file2:5
```

you can do that using the [`-h`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-_002dh) option.

Notice that both of these (using `-` as special file name and `-h` to suppress file names) are not required by POSIX, but at least GNU grep supports them.